# PHP: get property default value constant name using Reflection API

Tags: php, reflection

I need to be able to retrieve property default value constant name.
For example, having such class:

```
class Foo
{
    const BAR = 'BAR';
    private $baz = self::BAR;
}
```

I want to be able to do something like follows:

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass(Foo::class);
$reflection->getProperty('baz')->getDefaultValueConstantName(); // 'Foo::BAR'
```

The weird thing about PHP Reflection API is that `\ReflectionParameter` class has method `getDefaultValueConstantName()`, but `\ReflectionProperty` does not. I can get property default value using `\ReflectionClass::getDefaultProperties()`, but this method will return property default value, not constant name this value has been taken from. 
Is there any solution for getting property default value constant name, and is this feature at least planned for next releases of PHP?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be possible.

When you do `private $baz = self::BAR;`, you assign (only) the value of the constant self::BAR, not a reference. After that, there is no way with Reflection to know where the value comes from.

If you really want to know that, you can maybe use annotations (doc comments) and retrieve them by reflection.